# How to remove hidden divs from view source of a page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML Page, in which there are some hidden DIVs and these DIVs are visible vai view source of a page. These DIVs should not be visible to a user when they "view source" of the page.

How this can be done ? Perhaps Javascript or other solution?

Comment: why you need hidden divs? remove them from html page

Comment: answer is simple: you can't

Comment: Yes we can ! but server side ^_^

Comment: @Su4p are you making fun ;) if you remove it server side it won't be executed / rendered on the client....

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will only change the "computed source" so the client will still be able to see them. In order to really remove them you'll need to remove them server side.

Comment: when he removes them server side there is no reason at all to use them

Comment: I know, I'm just answering his question.

Comment: @Dukeatcoding Then he should store them server side in sessions.

Comment: @Houssni you are absolutely right, still it was not revealed so far why he uses this hidden divs in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can't really prevent a div from being read, because if you do, there will be no render of it.

It can be encrypted and generated via javascript. But once it is generated, user will be able to see it clearly in computed source.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing what you want. The source (in case of HTML) is just text containing HTML markup. The **show source** view in the browser shows it to you as it came from the server with added syntax highlighting, but unlike the **developer tools**, it doesn't reflect any **DOM** changes done with **Javascript**. Even if some browser had a feature to prevent some parts of the source from being displayed, users will still be able to open it in another browser or download the HTML as a file and examine the source in a text editor.

Answer (score -1):

You can not really hide the source code but you can encrypt it. What you transmit from Server to the Client will be in the client side browser and can be seen somehow.

With a tool like the one I just googled http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter it is possible to encrypt html.

It will encrypt your html code and you can insert it via javascript later. Encryption will not finally hide it from someone keen in using debugging tools. But a "normal" user won't see it directly in the source.

**Still you should be thinking about storing information you want to hide from the user server-side in a session or something.**

Comment: can be seen after generation via computed source.

Comment: @Apolo you might insert them on click just bevor sending information though

Comment: eurk this is ugly. In addition what the point cause you can still retrieve the source with firebug or tools like that. Or even show the computed source.

Comment: I am really waiting on the answer for what reason he tries to achive this at all... should be very hard to hide something in HTML at all since it is not complied or anything. In my opinion encryption is a good way to keep it away from the normal user. Most likely there is no other option.

Comment: @Dukeatcoding you can still see it if you set up breakpoints inside js code (firebug).

Comment: you are completly right... but to hide something in html from someone who can use debug tools seems to be very hard

Comment: actually i am using multi form ajax slider, in which step 2,step 3 forms are visible at step-1 only, when we view source the page and they are in hidden form. I just want the next step form should not be visible anywhere in step-1 via firebug or view source