# How can I remove empty title tag using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried many ways to remove  tag from the  part of my HTML document. But nothing is worked. My intention is to remove if  tag is empty. I checked few tutorials and nothing is wokred. I tried following codes.

```
document.querySelector("title").remove();
```

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].remove()
```

Comment: Looking at this bottom one of your two suggestions seems to work so maybe its an issue with how you are calling this function, can you give me a bit more information about how your doing this

Comment: @Stevo, i was tried the following.
`function removetitle(){
let a = document.querySelector("title");
a.remove();
}
removetitle();`

Comment: @Andreas, you says that the <title>  canot be controll by Javascript

Comment: Why would you want to do this? How does a empty `<title></title>`  cause any problems?

Comment: @Andreas, the problem is with one of my following website design: https://bitheights.com, when you check this, you able to see there is one empty tag is generating. I need to remove this because i have to make this website W3 validate. When i validate the website using W3 validation. There is an error showing regarding this as follows: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fbitheights.com%2F, i hope this make you aware of the issue.

Comment: Removing it wont make the website valid though, the validator says that it cannot be empty so removing it is not the answer and wont fix your issues, you need to look at what you should be populating it with, title is needed for things like SEO so it is actually important

Comment: @Stevo, I understand SEO mandatories. I use <title> tag once in the website using Custom fields. But my concern is another empty <title> tag is generating by WordPress. This is what i can't fix.

Answer (score 1):

Choose all title tags in document

```
document.querySelectorAll("title").forEach(element => {
    if (element.textContent == "") element.remove() // remove title if its empty
});
```

Comment: it worked when checking using the element in the Inspect. But when i check the code using 'view-source' the title is still there. Can we remove that also.

Comment: I think its impossible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250073/how-to-remove-hidden-divs-from-view-source-of-a-page)

Comment: Okay Yahya, let me try whether it will work in my W3 validation.